# Use arrayblocking queue as consumer producer to process huge file in spring design

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, producer-consumer

Currently in the controller of mvc spring :

```
FileHandlerService fileHandler = (FileHandlerService) lookupService.lookUp(FileType.find(fileExtension));

FileData fileData = FileUtils.getFileDataFromStream(fileHandler, file.getInputStream(), new Character('|'), new Character('\"'));
adhocService.uploadFile(fileData,file.getOriginalFilename(),tab,report,desc);
```

where file handler is just to know the file type to process whether exl,csv,txt.

File data is the map or columns and rows.

then i load all the file data in main memory and upload.

I need to do it using arrayBlockingQueue and producer and consumer thread to prevent memory from crashing.

**Can some one suggest a fine design ? like should i make a queueservice or something?**

Comment: Would you be able to give more information? How do you get ```file``` in current controller? What does current controller do if there is an exception in current flow (whatever your current logic is)? Does the controller need to know if adhocService.uploadFile was successful? Is it ok if controller can just confirm that ```file``` is "accepted" and actual status of "upload" will be provided later?

Comment: yes the file comes from a form that is an html form @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
   @RequestParam(value = "report", required = true) String report,
   @RequestParam(value = "desc", required = true) String desc,
   @RequestParam(value = "tab", required = false) String tab,
   HttpServletResponse res,
   BaseRequest req,
   HttpServletRequest request) {   and yes conroller throws the error back, I have a response object there i set false if there is an error and sets the msg